# YSlow - What does clicking add CDN do?

Tags: yslow, content-delivery-network

I was going over my YSlow results for an internal web application and I clicked the Add CDN button. Now I have an `A` rating for using a CDN.

What just happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the YSlow FAQ on [How do I add my CDN hostname to YSlow for Rule 2?](http://yslow.org/faq/#faq_cdn)

Comment: Ah, thanks. The help file does not explain that. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cdn