# add expire headers for static content google recaptcha

Tags: html5boilerplate, yslow, expires-header

I tested my site using Yslow and it states

There are 7 static components without a far-future expiration date.

> https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit&hl=en
>   http://www.searchanise.com/widgets/v1.0/init.js

Now I have seen that there is the HTML5Boilerplate project that has an excellent  .htaccess file with examples but I do not see how that can apply to findings on my site.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control expires headers or anything for content you're loading from other sites. You can only control things on your own site (that's what the `.htaccess` file from the boilerplate project would help with).

What you can do is review all those components being loaded from other sites to make sure they are still needed. I list some other strategies in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22057650/9965